# Arima and Sarima in python

Tags: python

I wanted to ask I am usually using `R` when I do time series but I am trying out `python` now.

When doing the Arima model I use `ARIMA` function 
But Can I also use `SARIMAX` function for just Arima models?

When I do `SARIMAX` order $= (2, 0, 4)$ (noseasonal parametrs) and then when I do `ARIMA` order $= (2, 0, 4) $

Outputs are not the same even thou the model should be the same?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are passing the same parameters to both Python classes: ARIMAX and SARIMAX... and this should produce the same answer, I agree.

The implementations are however separate, it seems - ARIMA inherits from ARMA models and SARIMAX inherits from MLEModel. Have a look at the source code for [**ARIMA**](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/arima_model.html#ARIMA) (search fro "*class ARIMA*") and [**SARIMAX**](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/sarimax.html#SARIMAX) (search for "*class SARIMAX*").

There are probably some different ordering of the operations, or different limits on the tolerances for MLE.